# Confirmation pop up message in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show a Success pop up to user after a succesful insertion command and when the user clicks Ok he should be redirected to a different view. can any one suggest

Comment: Currently i have created a new view for successful transaction.But I want that there should be popup on the same page ..and once user clicks ok he should be redirected to a different view

Comment: can you be more specific or post some of your code?

Comment: //after successful transaction
                        return RedirectToAction("Success","Success");

Comment: Post some code please. As far as i understood you can use `confirm('Want to redirect?')`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a pop-up in a browser, the Javascript is

```
alert("Success!");
```

And the next line of code will not execute until User clicks OK.  So you can add whatever code you want there to redirect to a different view, but there are lots of ways you could do that.